# Difference between these setDefaultCloseOperation statements

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm unable to understand the Difference between these two statements:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

And

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Where frame is the Object of JFrame Class.
These statements perform the same task.What is the difference?

Comment: [`EXIT_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE) is a *static* variable in [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) class.

Comment: But for the record, it should be `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` to allow other non-daemon threads to continue.  Setting `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is the crude equivalent of shooting the JVM in the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference in the way it is executed. Just in the first case you
access a [static field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE) through a JFrame instance (`frame`). In the second
case you access it by the class name itself (`JFrame`).

Answer (score 0):

It will not matter which you use, but Eclipse, the IDE I use, will throw a warning.. suggesting that I should access it statically.

JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE is a static variable, meaning that you don't need an object to access this variable.

For example, if you have multiple JFrame objects and each one needs to be closed, instead of writing out every single object's name to access this variable, you can simply use the Class name `JFrame` `.` and then the static variable `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

In addition, with java convention, all static variables are upper case.